# Batch COLOR script that accepts Color-names, Decimals and Hex Parameters

Tags: colors, batch-file, hex, names, decimal

I just finished my a Batch COLOR script that accepts Color-names, Decimals and Hex Parameters.

This script works exactly like the MS-Color command but it also accepts
decimals and color-names.

Run this script without perimeters for a full description including syntax and usage.

I am wondering if I did a good job or is there something that can be improved?

```
if    "%_TPfore%"=="A" set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID

@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%1"=="/?" goto HELP
if "%1"==""   goto HELP

goto BYPASSREMSTATEMENTS
rem ***********************************************************
rem * Easycolor was created by Edoctoor 2010                  *
rem * With the help from the good people at stackoverflow.com *
rem * For the good people at stackoverflow.com                *
rem *                                                         *
rem * Convert Color-name and Decimals Parmeters to Hex values *
rem * then pass the VALUES to the COLOR COMMAND               *
rem ***********************************************************
:BYPASSREMSTATEMENTS

set "_DEBUGGING=FALSE"
If "%_DEBUGGING%"=="TRUE" prompt=$g && echo on && cls

REM IF TWO PARMETERS GIVEN
IF NOT "%2"=="" call :TWOPAR %1 %2

REM IF ONE PARMETER GIVEN
set _OPback=%1
call :TWOPAR %_OPback:~0,1% %_OPback:~1,1%

goto :eof

rem ***********************************************************
rem * Convert Color-name and Decimals Parmeters to Hex values *
rem * then pass the VALUES to the COLOR COMMAND               *
rem ***********************************************************

:TWOPAR
set "_TPback=%1"
set "_TPfore=%2"
set "_ValidB=FALSE"
set "_ValidF=FALSE"

FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,9) DO (
    if "%_TPback%"=="%%B"                             set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
)

if /I "%_TPback%"=="Black"        set /A _TPback=0 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Blue"         set /A _TPback=1 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Green"        set /A _TPback=2 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Aqua"         set /A _TPback=3 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Red"          set /A _TPback=4 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Purple"       set /A _TPback=5 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Yellow"       set /A _TPback=6 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="White"        set /A _TPback=7 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="Gray"         set /A _TPback=8 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="LightBlue"    set /A _TPback=9 && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="LightGreen"   set    _TPback=A && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="LightAqua"    set    _TPback=B && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="LightRed"     set    _TPback=C && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="LightPurple"  set    _TPback=D && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="LightYellow"  set    _TPback=E && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if /I "%_TPback%"=="BrightWhite"  set    _TPback=F && set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="A"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="B"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="C"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="D"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="E"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="F"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="a"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="b"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="c"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="d"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="e"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE
if    "%_TPback%"=="f"                                set "_ValidB=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_FORE

:TWOPAR_FORE

FOR /L %%B IN (1,1,9) DO (
    if "%_TPfore%"=="%%B"                             set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
)

if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Black"        set /A _TPfore=0 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Blue"         set /A _TPfore=1 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Green"        set /A _TPfore=2 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Aqua"         set /A _TPfore=3 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Red"          set /A _TPfore=4 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Purple"       set /A _TPfore=5 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Yellow"       set /A _TPfore=6 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="White"        set /A _TPfore=7 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="Gray"         set /A _TPfore=8 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="LightBlue"    set /A _TPfore=9 && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="LightGreen"   set    _TPfore=A && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="LightAqua"    set    _TPfore=B && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="LightRed"     set    _TPfore=C && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="LightPurple"  set    _TPfore=D && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="LightYellow"  set    _TPfore=E && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if /I "%_TPfore%"=="BrightWhite"  set    _TPfore=F && set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="A"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="B"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="C"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="D"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="E"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="F"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="a"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="b"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="c"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="d"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="e"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID
if    "%_TPfore%"=="f"                                set "_ValidF=TRUE" && goto TWOPAR_VALID

:TWOPAR_VALID

If "%_DEBUGGING%"=="TRUE" (
    echo TWOPAR Background is %_TPback% %_ValidB%
    echo TWOPAR Foreground is %_TPfore% %_ValidF%
    pause
)

rem I think I can remove this as the color command
rem will provide the errolevel if the values are equal...
rem Is that right?
rem if Background Parameter matches Foreground ignore
rem IF "%_TPback%"=="%_TPfore%" (
rem     set _TrueIFMatch=%errorlevel%
rem     exit %_TrueIFMatch%
rem ) 

if "%_ValidB%"=="TRUE" (
    if "%_ValidF%"=="TRUE" (
        color %_TPback%%_TPfore%
    )
)
exit /B

rem ***********************************************************
rem * Display Help and exit                                   *
rem ***********************************************************

:HELP
@echo off
echo.
echo Sets the default console background and foreground text colors.
echo. 
echo EASYCOLOR ^[Background Decimal Code^]  ^[Text Decimal Code^]
echo EASYCOLOR ^[Background   Color-Name^]  ^[Text Color-Name^]
echo.
echo EASYCOLOR is compatable with the COLOR command see color /?
echo.
echo EASYCOLOR ^[Background HEX CODE Text HEX CODE^]
echo. 
echo Color attributes are specified by Decimal, Color-Names, or Hex digits
echo The first  ^(Decimal, Color-Names, Hex^) value corresponds to the background color;
echo the second ^(Decimal, Color-Names, Hex^) value corresponds to the text color.
echo Each attribute can be any of the following values:
echo. 
echo     Decimal == Color-Names == Hex
echo     _____________________________
echo          0  == Black ======== 0
echo          1  == Blue ========= 1
echo          2  == Green ======== 2
echo          3  == Aqua ========= 3
echo          4  == Red ========== 4
echo          5  == Purple ======= 5
echo          6  == Yellow ======= 6
echo          7  == White ======== 7
echo          8  == Gray ========= 8
echo          9  == LightBlue ==== 9
echo          10 == LightGreen === A
echo          11 == LightAqua ==== B
echo          12 == LightRed ===== C
echo          13 == LightPurple == D
echo          14 == LightYellow == E
echo          15 == BrightWhite == F
echo.
echo Help Examples:
echo.
echo EASYCOLOR                  ^> produces this help screen.
echo EASYCOLOR /?               ^> produces this help screen.
echo.
echo Decimal and Color-Names Examples:
echo.
echo EASYCOLOR 7 0              ^> White background with Black text.
echo EASYCOLOR Blue White       ^> Blue  background with White text. 
echo EASYCOLOR 0 LightGreen     ^> Black background with LightGreen text.
echo.
echo Color command and compatable Hex Examples: 
echo (Note: Hex is assumed if no space between attributes)
echo.
echo EASYCOLOR 0F               ^> Black background with BrightWhite text. 
echo EASYCOLOR 1B               ^> Blue  background with LightAqua text. 
echo.
echo Note
echo.
echo EASYCOLOR 0brightwhite     ^> Black background with LightAqua text.
echo Because there wasn't a space between 0 and brightwhite
echo the HEX value of 0b is assumed; wrongly.
echo. 
echo EASYCOLOR 0 brightwhite    ^> Black background with brightwhite text.
echo as expected.
echo.
echo The EASYCOLOR command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if an attempt is made to execute
echo the EASYCOLOR command with a foreground and background color that are the
echo same.
echo. 
echo. 
exit /B
```

[Click here to download the complete solution](http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=KNfbicbR)

Comment: You could decrease the size with a few FOR loops. Such as having a "map" or "color" variable that had all the colors in it separated by spaces, and have a FOR loop go through it and see if any of the tokens match the color specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nice script for the first one.

But one error I found here

```
REM IF TWO PARMETERS GIVEN
IF NOT "%2"=="" call :TWOPAR %1 %2

REM IF ONE PARMETER GIVEN
set _OPback=%1
call :TWOPAR %_OPback:~0,1% %_OPback:~1,1%
```

If two parameters present, you call :TWOPAR, but it will return, so the "ONE PARMETER GIVEN" part will also be executed.

And another general code suggestions.

Don't repeat yourself :-)
If code blocks are nearly same, it is better to merge them to a function.
Like your two verifications of the color names for the background and forground color.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%1"=="/?" goto HELP
if "%1"==""   goto HELP

goto BYPASSREMSTATEMENTS
rem ***********************************************************
rem * Easycolor was created by Edoctoor 2010                  *
rem * With the help from the good people at stackoverflow.com *
rem * For the good people at stackoverflow.com                *
rem *                                                         *
rem * Convert Color-name and Decimals Parmeters to Hex values *
rem * then pass the VALUES to the COLOR COMMAND               *
rem ***********************************************************
:BYPASSREMSTATEMENTS

set "_DEBUGGING=FALSE"
If "%_DEBUGGING%"=="TRUE" prompt=$g && echo on && cls

REM IF TWO PARMETERS GIVEN
IF NOT "%2"=="" call :TWOPAR %1 %2 & goto :eof

REM IF ONE PARMETER GIVEN

set _OPback=%1
call :TWOPAR %_OPback:~0,1% %_OPback:~1,1%

goto :eof

rem ***********************************************************
rem * Convert Color-name and Decimals Parmeters to Hex values *
rem * then pass the VALUES to the COLOR COMMAND               *
rem ***********************************************************

:TWOPAR
set "_TPback=%1"
set "_TPfore=%2"

call :AnalyzeParam _TPback _ValidB
call :AnalyzeParam _TPfore _ValidF

If "%_DEBUGGING%"=="TRUE" (
    echo TWOPAR Background is %_TPback% %_ValidB%
    echo TWOPAR Foreground is %_TPfore% %_ValidF%
    pause
)

rem I think I can remove this as the color command
rem will provide the errolevel if the values are equal...
rem Is that right?
rem if Background Parameter matches Foreground ignore
rem IF "%_TPback%"=="%_TPfore%" (
rem     set _TrueIFMatch=%errorlevel%
rem     exit %_TrueIFMatch%
rem ) 

if "%_ValidB%"=="TRUE" (
    if "%_ValidF%"=="TRUE" (
        color %_TPback%%_TPfore%
    )
)
exit /B

:AnalyzeParam <paramVariable>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "value=!%1!"
set "valid=FALSE"

set "color[0]=Black"
set "color[1]=Blue"
set "color[2]=Green"
set "color[3]=Aqua"
set "color[4]=Red"
set "color[5]=Purple"
set "color[6]=Yellow"
set "color[7]=White"
set "color[8]=Gray"
set "color[9]=LightBlue"
set "color[10]=LightGreen"
set "color[11]=LightAqua"
set "color[12]=LightRed"
set "color[13]=LightPurple"
set "color[14]=LightYellow"
set "color[15]=BrightWhite"
for /L %%n in (0,1,15) DO (
    if /I !color[%%n]!==!value! (
        set "value=%%n"
        set "valid=TRUE"
        goto :AnalyzeParam_valid
    )
)
rem Test if it is a legal hex nibble character
if /I !value! GEQ A (
    if !value! LEQ F (
        set "valid=TRUE"
    )
) ELSE if !value! GEQ 0 (
    if !value! LEQ 9 (
        set "valid=TRUE"
    )
)
:AnalyzeParam_valid
(
   ENDLOCAL
   set %~1=%value%
   set %~2=%valid%
   goto :eof
)
```

hope it helps
jeb

Comment: Most of the techniques that you have used are over-my-head, thank you for showing me how to use more advance techniques.

Comment: goto :AnalyzeParam_valid is a technique that I was looking for; yet, I still don't understand it at this time. I'll keep reviewing this tidbit until I do. Thank you for taking the time to totally rewrite the script.

Comment: Question: Now that you have completed this Question. Do I copy your answer into the area where my question is? Because your answer is missing :HELP and I want your corrections and the :HELP to be all in one place. Sorry, if this is a dumb question.

Comment: There aren't dump questions, only dump answers ..., I only want to show the relavant part. And no, I wouldn't copy this code to your question, others couldn't understand the question and the answer anymore. Simply copy it to your batch file and be happy ;-)

Comment: Personal matter of taste: For variables that contain a boolean I usually check for them with `if defined var` instead of comparing to a value which is usually more robust against typos and the like.